# Use of "That" as a single word in a sentence

Tags: that

I've heard this kind of phrase recently.

> When your shoelaces come undone and you trip. **That**.

I'm confused about the use of *That*. Any comments?

Comment: I've seen "This" and "That" used as a way of emphasis in written communication. Usually things like Facebook, other social media, and text messaging.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I think what the speaker says beforehand is more important. (I think this one-word sentence is a shorthand for _That's a good example of what I was just talking about._)

Comment: Context is key. Do you know what was said/expressed just before your example?

Comment: @JCG "What really makes you annoyed?"?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Come again? Oh......now I get it, good one!

Comment: @JCG I was hoping you weren't too strait-laced to see it as not a personal inquiry.

Comment: When you trip that way, isn't it because you're straight-laced?

Answer (score 1):

Generally occurs immediately after the description of some scenario:

```
You know when someone ties your shoestrings together and you trip?  That.
```

Basically, it's short for "I'm talking about that scenario."

I suppose, by the "rules" of elision in English, it can be argued to be "legal" syntax, though it's probably best considered to be "informal".

Answer (score 0):

It's an emphasis. As in, "that really ruined my moment".